# Is it possible to access the app.config file when an exe is used as a dll?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, appsettings

I have a command line application that reads some settings from the app.config file, using the usual `Properties.Settings.blabla` properties.

This application is also used as a dll.

When I use it as a dll, it ignores any foo.exe.config that I drop in the directory. It doesn't throw an exception as I expected when using the methods that access the config file, but it doesn't take the config file either.

Is there a way to have an exe that is being used as a dll consume its own settings file, and still have it use the app.config file when used an an exe? I don't want to change neither the consumer code, and I want as little impact as possible on the exe code.

I've seen solutions using `ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration` Method or `OpenExeConfiguration`, is the solution using those methods inside the exe code? That way it will always look for the config file, regardless of if it is being used as dll or exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do that, you'll need to read specifically from that file. A .NET executable reads from it's own `app.config` file. Library code *always* reads from the `app.config` file for the application being executed... even library code that just happens to have been compiled into a file with an .exe extension.

**Edit for Emphasis/Clarification**
When I speak of an `app.config`, I am of course talking about the appropriately-renamed `[program.exe.config]` file.

Comment: I use .dll's currently to call for example the name of the config file is jobs.config but we have created a WorkerAgent class that inherits from things such as System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings have you tried looking at the .config file that's the same name as your .dll / console application name at runtime it doesn't look at app.config

Comment: So, let's use an example to make things clearer. Suppose I have an application called myapp, and a library called mylib. mylib is an exe (which can be executed on its own actually) but is is referenced by myapp. mylib uses the usual Properties.Settings.blabla to read from a config file.
If, during the execution of myapp, a method from mylib is called, that uses Properties.Settings.blabla, where would that read from? myapp.exe.config or mylib.exe.config?? From your answer, I assume that it would reado from myapp.exe.config, right? And what if that setting doesn't exist there?

Comment: @Juancentro Your assumption is correct; because in this case, `myapp.exe` is the program currently executing, the configuration would be read from `myapp.exe.config`. I don't know offhand what would happen if, therefore, the appropriate configuration for the Settings was missing; I expect either an exception related to the missing config, or loading of default values (zeros or `null`, which could likely cause exceptions, anyway)